# How to do wamp server turning on?

Tags: wampserver

I installed the wamp server successfully and also install the install the C++ Redistributable. I also change the port no to 80 to 80885.

I also change the settings in skype, `Skype --> Tools --> Options --> Advanced --> Connection` and turn off "Use port 80 and 443 as alternatives for incoming connections.

But still when I am starting the server it is showing on line but giving orange color, and when I am usng it on browsre it is no running.

Comment: Port 80885? That's not a valid port number, max is 65535.

Comment: You should also check the system logs for messages.

Comment: sorry my port no is 8085.

Answer (score 0):

Install visual c++ redistribution setup [here](http://www.microsoft.com/en-pk/download/details.aspx?id=5555) on your machine x64 or x 86 according to your machine. Also make sure you have msvcr.dll in your `windows/system` forlder. If not then download and paste there. Then restart the wamp server. You might need to allow it through first time running.
Also use port 80 it is fine.

Comment: I installed visualc++ x86 on my machine. But still not working.
Can you tell, me where I can get windows/system folder.

Comment: i mean to say that in windows where your operating system is installed. It is usually in C drive if you have partitions

Comment: Ok raheel, now i installed wamp server successfully but, when i am going on to http://localhost/phpmyadmin/, then it is asking about username and password. So what is my username and passwor, because i didn't give any username and password

Comment: I got the answer. The username is 'root' and password is null, means no password and it works.thanks raheen.